# dapper select single as nested object

Tags: c#, dapper

I a trying to understand why I cannot query a single complex(nested) result with Dapper (just started learning). Any tips would be welcomed.

Parent object:

```
public record Requirement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<System> Systems { get; set; }
}
```

Child Object:

```
public record System 
{
    public int SysId { get; set; }
    public int ReqId {get;set;}
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I seems that I cannot add a mapping function to QuerySingleOrDefault. Best I could do was this (and it does not feel right):

```
string sql = $@"select req.Id, 
    req.Text, 
    sys.SysId,
    sys.ReqId,
    sys.Code,
    from Requirements req
    join Systems sys on req.Id = sys.ReqId
    where req.Id = {request.id}";

return (await con.QueryAsync<Requirement,
                    System,
                    Requirement>(sql, (req, reqSystem) =>
                    {
                        RequirementResponse requirement = req;
                        requirement.Systems = new List<System>();
                        requirement.Systems.Add(reqSystem);
                        return requirement;
                    }, splitOn: "Id, SysId "
                    )).AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You're using Dapper. Dapper already has support for parameterized queries. Use that instead of string concatination.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `AsQueryable` before the `FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 3):

Because you have a join you get multiple rows in your resultset. Your mapping action is called once for each row. So, you get multiple RequirementResponse with one system each. You need to create only one.

```cs
string sql = $@"select req.Id, 
    req.Text, 
    sys.SysId,
    sys.ReqId,
    sys.Code,
    from Requirements req
    join Systems sys on req.Id = sys.ReqId
    where req.Id = @RequestId";

RequirementResponse requirement = null;
await con.QueryAsync<Requirement, System, Requirement>(sql, 
    (req, reqSystem) =>
    {
        if (requirement == null)
        {
            requirement = req;
            requirement.Systems = new List<System>();
        }
        requirement.Systems.Add(reqSystem);
        return requirement; // This return doesn't matter, you will not be using it
    }, 
    param: new { RequestId = request.id },
    splitOn: "SysId "
);
return requirement;
```

You also only need one column in splitOn, since the result row should only be split in two parts.

Also notice I've made it a parameterized query. As others have noted string concatenation is not recommended for building SQL queries because of SQL injection.